# send string from controller to view

Tags: ember.js, view, controller, handlebars.js

I'm just starting out on some ember.js, and am pretty inexperienced.  This is probably a very simple question to answer but I can't seem to get it to work.  I'm in the controller for my chart trying to set range using

```
    range: function() {
    var dataArr = this.get("rawData");
    if (!dataArr) return;
    var range = "";
    var xmax = -1 * Infinity;
    var xmin = Infinity;
    var ymax = -1 * Infinity;
    var ymin = Infinity;

    code to figure out xmin, max etc......

    lowerBound = new Date(xmin)
    upperBound = new Date(xmax)
    range = d3.time.format.utc("%a, %b%e %-I:%M %p")(lowerBound) + " - " + d3.time.format.utc("%a, %b%e %-I:%M %p")(upperBound);
    return range
  }.observes('display', 'rawData'),
```

I then try to use this with handlebars {{range}} and it does not work... I dont know if I'm providing enough info but if anyone can help out its much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Range should be a computed property, check out the observer [docs](http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/observers/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to identify your `range` property as a property, thusly:

```
range: function() {
    var dataArr = this.get("rawData");
    // blah blah, your implementation
    return range;
  }.property('rawData'),
```

By specifying `rawData` as a dependency, Ember will automatically recompute `range` if `rawData` changes.